# CloudFront-powered website is redirected to s3 bucket url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I've got a static-hosting enable S3 bucket. There's also a cloudfront distribution that is being powered by that bucket.

I've added a CNAME entry to the cloudfront distribution for "mywebsite.com"

and when I go to load "mywebsite.com" in my browser, it redirects to `http://my-bucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/index.html`

Why is this redirect happening? how do I stop that hostname from being rewritten?

**Edit: here's the setup details after some suggested changes:**

- **cloudfront** - ***alternate domain***: mysite.com
- **cloudfront** - ***alternate domain***: www.mysite.com
- **cloudfront** - ***origin***: my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
- **route53** - ***hosted zone***: mysite.com
- **route53** - ***A record***: 12345.cloudfront.net
- **route53** - ***CNAME***: www.mysite.com --> mysite.com

**and the effects of this setup:**

- Loading: `mysite.com` --> 301 redirects to `my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
- Loading: `www.mysite.com` --> 301 redirects to `my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
- Loading: `my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` --> 200 Success
- Loading: `d1h3yk3zemxpnb.cloudfront.net` --> 301 redirects to `my-bucket.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
- Loading: `http://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/` --> permissions error

Comment: Wait a day and see if it is still happening. I've heard that some redirects take a while to update.

Comment: Did you add the domain name in cloud front in "Alternate Domain Names" ?

Comment: See updates above

Comment: Was the issue fixed? Even I'm seeing a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is a side effect of a misconfiguration.  This specific behavior may go away within a few minutes or hours of bucket creation, but the underlying issue won't be resolved.

When configuring a static website hosting enabled bucket behind CloudFront, you don't want to select the bucket name from the list of buckets.

> On the Create Distribution page, in the Origin Settings section, for Origin Domain Name, type the Amazon S3 static website hosting endpoint for your bucket. For example, `example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`.
>
> **Note**
>
> Be sure to specify the static website hosting endpoint, not the name of the bucket.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html#create-distribution

Selecting the `example.com.s3.amazonaws.com` entry from the list, rather than typing in the bucket's website hosting endpoint, would be the most likely explanation of this behavior.

S3 updates the DNS for the global REST endpoint hierarchy `*.s3.amazonaws.com` with a record sending requests to the right region for the bucket within a short time after bucket creation, and CloudFront appears rely on this for sending the requests to the right place.  Before that initial update is complete, S3 will return a redirect and CloudFront returns that redirect to the browser... but all of this indicates that you didn't use the static website hosting endpoint as the origin domain name.

Comment: This is it! and this isn't very well documented, I had to read this and the docs a few times to finally see the difference. On the S3 Properties page take the URI provided in the Static Hosting section and not the bucket URI.

Answer (score 0):

From AWS support https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216814

---

> This is an expected behavior when you create a new bucket. The
> following pages explains the concept:
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html
>
> "Amazon S3 routes any virtual hosted–style requests to the US East (N.
> Virginia) region by default if you use the US East (N. Virginia)
> endpoint (s3.amazonaws.com), instead of the region-specific endpoint
> (for example, s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com). When you create a bucket,
> in any region, Amazon S3 updates DNS to reroute the request to the
> correct location, which might take time. In the meantime, the default
> rule applies and your virtual hosted–style request goes to the US East
> (N. Virginia) region, and Amazon S3 redirects it with HTTP 307
> redirect to the correct region."
>
> Please give some time to S3 until the domain name becomes ready
> (normally an hour or so). Also, please note, errors are cached in
> CloudFront by default. This means "307 Temporary Redirect" is cached
> for 300 seconds unless you change it:
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html
>
> In order to test your cloudfront again, please make sure the cache has
> been invalidated:
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html
>
> Hope that helps.

---

The default cache policy has

```
Default TTL 86400
```

That is, 24h, so you may want to invalidate it rather than wait.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

---

> If you use the AWS command line interface (CLI) for invalidating files
> and you specify a path that includes the * wildcard, you must use
> quotes (") around the path.
>
> For example: aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id
> distribution_ID --paths "/*"

---

Another thing you can do if nothing of the above works and you are in development and just want to get something accessible is to change the reference or your bucket from

```
global — {bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com
```

to

```
regional — {bucket-name}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com
```

As explained on the forum this will bypass the attempt to use the replicated buckets by going just to one, which will not fail and therefore you won't get a redirect.

You will see that easily with `curl`

```
$ curl -I http://blah.cloudfront.net/x.svg
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Content-Type: application/xml
Connection: keep-alive
x-amz-bucket-region: eu-west-1


$ curl -I http://blah.cloudfront.net/x.svg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Length: 657
Connection: keep-alive
```